# Weird ?? en_US?? appearing in options tag

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

Currently i have this code in the Spring MVC to populate all the options such as "Doctor" etc...

```
@ModelAttribute("allTypes")
public List<String> populateType() {
String a[]= new String[]{"Doctor","Patient"}; 
return Arrays.asList(a);
}
```

And this piece of code in HTML where it uses the above code to display the options in the dropdown list.

```
<select th:field="*{type}">
<option value="NONE">------Select-------</option>
<option th:each="type:${allTypes}" th:value="${type}" th:text="#{${type}}"></option>
</select>
```

The problem i encountered is that i have weird ouput on the dropdown list. For instance 
??Doctor_en_US??, ??Patient_en_US??.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Appears to be an issue with your internationalisation configuration somewhere

Comment: i just realised i made a mistake at the th:text it should be the same as th:value now it is displaying the correct values.

Comment: I'd pretty much recommend against using arrays (in this case, you could use `Arrays.asList("Doctor", "Patient")`) and variable names like `a`. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `??Something_en_US??` strings appear when using Thymeleaf message expressions (`#{...}`) and Message Resolver cannot resolve the message code found within that expression.  So for example, `#{foo}` would require a line in the messages properties file with something like:

```
foo = Some message or text to display here
```

Message resolution varies depending on whether or not Thymeleaf is configured with or without the Spring dialect.  References:

- Message Resolvers in http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#message-resolvers
- `MessageSource` throughout http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html#spring-mvc-configuration